# Property linked to users defaults causing app to crash

Tags: ios, swift

Do properties in my initial view controller get set before or after AppDelegate function didFinishLaunchingWithOptions gets called?

Here is the code in AppDelegate. When my app first starts up, if the user default for "CurrentDateBool" has not been set, it gets set to true.

```
  func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    if UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "currentDateBool") == nil {
      UserDefaults.standard.setValue(true, forKey: "currentDateBool")
    }
    return true
}
```

Here is my initial view controller. This crashes my app on the currentDateBool property because it is nil. However, it should not be nil as it set it to true in AppDelegate. I thought that AppDelegate gets set before the initial view controller. Can someone please clarify the order in which the properties get set?

```
class TimestampTableViewController: UITableViewController {

  var currentDateBool = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "currentDateBool") as! Bool

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()  
  }
 ...
}
```

I can get it to work if I move setting the currentDateBool property to the user default in viewDidLoad.

```
class TimestampTableViewController: UITableViewController {

  var currentDateBool = true

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()  
    currentDateBool = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "currentDateBool") as! Bool
  }
 ...
}
```

Comment: "I can get it to work if I move setting the currentDateBool property to the user default in viewDidLoad." So do that!

Comment: @matt I did! haha. I'm just trying to understand why it's crashing when I don't. I thought AppDelegate gets called before my properties are set so I don't understand why it crashes.

Comment: Is TimestampTableViewController your root view controller? Are you using a main storyboard?

Comment: @matt yes it's my root view controller and I am using a main storyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can get it to work if I move setting the `currentDateBool` property to the user default in `viewDidLoad`

Exactly so. And that is precisely what you should do.

You are using a main storyboard. This means that your initial interface is loaded from the storyboard, *before* the code in your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is run. Thus, although TimestampTableViewController does not yet have a *view*, it does *exist* — meaning that it has been instantiated, and thus its properties have been given their initial value.

To see that this is true, just make a basic vanilla project, like this:

```
// in the app delegate

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    print("one")
    return true
}

// in the main view controller

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let what : Void = {print("two")}()
}
```

You will see `two`, then `one`, in the console.

But if you move `what` into `viewDidLoad`, you will see `one`, then `two`. That's because in this situation, the view controller's *view* does not load until *after* your code in the app delegate runs.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense!